# c sscanf with character delimiter

Tags: c, io, scanf

I have an input string of the form

```
char *s = "one.two three"
```

and I want to separate it into 3 string variables.
I'm doing

```
sscanf(s, "%s.%s %s", one, two, three);
```

but it's reading in "one.two" as the string for variable one. How do I handle the "." and the whitespace with sscanf?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `%s` specifier only stops for a space. Try something like:

```
sscanf(s, "%[^.].%s %s", one, two, three);
```

---

Interestingly, it's likely impossible to produce an acceptable input for `"%s.%s %s"` since `%s` only stops for a space yet a `.` must immediately follow it.

Comment: Just when you thought you knew everything about scanf format specifiers =P

Comment: I would be very sur... I _am_ very surprised that this actually works :-)